# Resolver en la vista una promesa de una funcion que recibe datos de una API

Tags: nodejs, api, promesas, handlebars.js, gcloud

Estoy Realizando un proyecto el cual ocupa "Google Cloud Storage"de GCP en el manejo de archivos de audio, los cuales quiero reproducir en una vista con la etiqueta audio de html. Al momento de obtener los datos de la funcion que hace contacto con la API estoy trabajando con una funcion asíncrona, por lo cual al momento te llamar al script desde la vista recibo solamente una promesa y no el valor de la promesa resuelta, que en este caso seria un String de la función "getSignedUrl" de Google Cloud Storage. ¿como puedo desde la vista esperar a que se resuelva la promesa antes de usar el dato?

```
function geturlaudio() {
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
  keyFilename: path.join(__dirname, '../apikeys/reforzamientoalgebraia-017aa4b76248.json'),
  projectId: 'reforzamientoalgebraia'
});
const audioaibucket = storage.bucket('audios-ai');
const file = audioaibucket.file('bienvenida.mp3');
const config = {
  action: 'read',
  expires: '03-17-2025'
};

  file.getSignedUrl(config, (err, url) => {
    if (err) {
     console.error(err);
     return;
    }
    console.log(url);
    return url;
   });
```

Esta es la vista que llama al script que guarda la url en la variable:

```
<main class="index">
    <header class="fondoia d-flex">
        
         <audio src= {{tts}} autoplay></audio>
        
    </header>
</main>
```

Si bien estoy obteniendo la url en el console log, la vista la recibe como promesa.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu código debe ir en formato texto y [no en imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-código-vale-más-que-mil-imágenes-cómo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu/3976#3976). Saludos

Comment: no veo el llamado al render

Answer (score 0):

al ser una promesa, debes ejecutar lo que quieres hacer (en este caso obtener la url) despues de que se ejecute y colocarlo dentro de un .then() ya que javascript es sincrono, osea el codigo sigue leyendo independiente de si llego la respuesta o no, y esta respuesta no llega instantanea, se demora.
por ejemplo:

```
file.getSignedUrl(config).then(signedUrls => {

   // este codigo se ejejcutara cuando llegue la respuesta
   let myUrl = signedUrls[0] // mi URL
   console.log(myUrl);

}).catch(err=>{

   console.log(error);

});
```

ahora, si lo que buscas que la respuesta del getSignedUrl se guarde en una variable de forma asíncrona, puedes usar una promesa **pero todo tu código deberá ser introducido dentro de una función asincrona**

```
let myUrl = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   file.getSignedUrl(config).then(signedUrls => {

       // este codigo se ejejcutara cuando llegue la respuesta
       let myUrl = signedUrls[0] // mi URL
       resolve(myUrl); // esto es el return de la promesa

    }).catch(err=>{

       console.log(error);
       reject(error)
    });

});
```

Comment: Hola Jhonnatan muchas gracias por la respuesta, muy bien explicado todo. Mi problema realmente es otro, cuando llamo al script desde la vista se me guarda la url dentro de la variable como explicas tu, pero el tema es que yo quiero en la misma vista donde llamo al script que guarda la url en la variable usar esta variable, pero como despues de la ejecucion la respuesta no llega instantanea esta no la puedo usar en la vista.

Comment: debes setear una variable global al principio de tu código y simplemente almacenar la url que llega de la peticion en esta variable global. asi podras acceder ella siempre. te recomiendo usar patron singleton